# Deep Q learning-Training issue

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

A snake game was created using Pygame and I tried to solve it using an AI. Initially I didn't increase the body length to check if the snake head moves towards the food. Grid size is 5*5. DDQN network was used. Most of time the head moves towards the wall or gets struck in a continuous loop.The maximum score attained was  4 even if I train it for 5000 episodes.

**State:** It is an array of size 16. The first 8 values has the distance between the head and wall at 8 directions(left , left top, top, right top, right , right bottom, bottom, left bottom). Next 8 values has the distance between head and food at 8 directions. All the values are in the range 0 to 1. 1 means the object is near and 0 means it is very far.

**Action :** There are 3 actions 0,1,2. 0- Head moves in same direction. 1- Head turns left. 2- Head turns right.

**Reward:** Reward of +50 if it collects the food and reward of -200 if it touches the wall.

I am not able to understand why my neural network learns in the wrong way. Please do help me solve this issue. I have attached the code here.

**Code:**

```
import pygame
pygame.font.init()
import time
import random
import numpy as np
from math import hypot
from collections import deque
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import os
seeds = 1001
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seeds)
np.random.seed(seeds)
random.seed(seeds)
tf.random.set_seed(seeds)
batch = 16

class Food:
def __init__(self,width,n):
    self.width = width
    self.n = n
    self.size = width //n
    self.blocks = self.blocks_total()
    
def blocks_total(self):# Total available positions
    x = y = 0
    s=[]
    for i in range(self.n):
        for j in range(self.n):
            s.append([x,y])
            y += self.size
        x += self.size
        y = 0
    return s

def food_pos(self,s):# Random food position
    food_blocks = self.blocks_total()
    try:
        for i in self.blocks:
            for j in s:
                if i[0] == j[0] and i[1] == j[1]:
                    food_blocks.remove([j[0],j[1]])
                    break
        a = random.choice(food_blocks)
        return a
    except:
        return 0.1,0.1
    
class Agent:
def __init__(self,width,n,state_size,action_size=3,gamma = 0.98):
    self.width = width
    self.n = n
    self.size = width //n
    self.state_size = state_size
    self.action_size = action_size
    self.gamma = gamma
    self.epsilon = 1
    self.epsilon_min = 0
    self.epsilon_decay = 0.99
    self.memory = deque(maxlen=5000)
    self.model = self.build_model()
    self.train_model = self.build_model()
    
def reshape(self,state):# Reshaping state for input in nueral network
    return np.reshape(state,[1,state.shape[0]])

def build_model(self):# Nueral network
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(16,input_shape=(self.state_size,),activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(12,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(12,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=Adam(0.0001))
    return model

def get_action(self,state):
    if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
        return random.randint(0,2)
    a = self.reshape(state)
    p = self.model.predict(a)
    return np.argmax(p[0])

def remember(self,state,action,reward,new_state,done): # Saving in memory
    self.memory.append((state,action,reward,new_state,done))

def replay(self): # Training of nueral network
    minibatch = random.sample(self.memory,batch)
    for state,action,reward,new_state,done in minibatch:
        target = reward
        state = self.reshape(state)
        new_state = self.reshape(new_state)
        if not done:
            target = reward +(self.gamma*(np.max(self.train_model.predict(new_state)[0])))
        target_f = self.model.predict(state)
        target_f[0][action] = target
        
        self.model.fit(state,target_f,epochs =1, verbose = 0)
        
    if self.epsilon  > self.epsilon_min:
        self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
        
def save_model(self):
    self.model.save_weights('nn1.h5')
    
def load_model(self):
    self.train_model.load_weights('nn1.h5')

class Game:
def __init__(self,width=500,n=5):
    self.width = width
    self.n = n
    self.size = width//n
    self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,width))
    pygame.display.set_caption('A')
    self.food = Food(width,n)
    self.agent = Agent(width, n, state_size=16)
    self.game_over = False
    self.dirc = 'r'# starting direction of snake
    self.snake_list = []
    self.snake_length = 1
    self.wall_touch = False
    
def display_player(self,disp,s_list,dirc):# displaying the snake head and its eyes
    l = len(s_list)
    if l > self.snake_length:
        del s_list[0]
        l -=1
    for idx,i in enumerate(s_list):
        if idx == l-1:
            pygame.draw.rect(disp,(255,255,255),(i[0],i[1],self.size-1,self.size-1))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(disp,(255,165,0),(i[0],i[1],self.size-1,self.size-1))
    a = s_list.copy()
    x,y = a.pop()
    rad = 10
    if dirc == 'u':
        pygame.draw.circle(disp,(0,0,0),(x+50,y+30),rad)
    elif dirc == 'd':
        pygame.draw.circle(disp,(0,0,0),(x+50,y+70),rad)
    elif dirc == 'r':
        pygame.draw.circle(disp,(0,0,0),(x+70,y+49),rad)
    elif dirc == 'l':
        pygame.draw.circle(disp,(0,0,0),(x+30,y+49),rad)
        
def move(self,dirc,s_list):# Constantly moving the snake on that particular direction
    x,y = s_list.pop()
    if dirc == 'l':
        x -= self.size
        if x <0:
            x = 0
            self.wall_touch = True
    elif dirc == 'r':
        x += self.size
        if x > self.width - self.size:
            x = self.width - self.size
            self.wall_touch = True
    elif dirc == 'u':
        y -= self.size
        if y <0:
            y = 0
            self.wall_touch = True
    elif dirc == 'd':
        y += self.size
        if y > self.width - self.size:
            y = self.width - self.size
            self.wall_touch = True
    self.snake_list.append([x,y])
    
def check_food_collect(self,fx,fy,s_list):# Check if head position and food position are same
    x,y =s_list.pop()
    if x == fx and y == fy:
        return True
    return False

def display_msg(self,msg,font='freesansbold.ttf',size=15,color=(255,255,255),loc=(410,15)):
    mymsg = pygame.font.Font(font,size).render(msg,True,color)
    self.display.blit(mymsg,loc)
    
def get_direction(self,change):# Changing the direction of snake based on the current direction
    if self.dirc == 'r':
        if change == 'r':
            self.dirc= 'd'
        elif change == 'l':
            self.dirc= 'u'
            
    elif self.dirc == 'l':
        if change == 'r':
            self.dirc= 'u'
        elif change == 'l':
            self.dirc= 'd'
            
    elif self.dirc == 'd' :
        if change == 'r':
            self.dirc= 'l'
        elif change == 'l':
            self.dirc= 'r'
            
    elif self.dirc == 'u':
        if change == 'r':
            self.dirc= 'r'
        elif change == 'l':
            self.dirc= 'l'
        
def near_wall(self,n,s_list): # Distance of nearby wall
    a,b = n
    x,y = s_list.pop()
    i =0
    while True:
        xx = x +(self.size * i * a)
        yy = y +(self.size * i * b)
        dis = abs(xx-x)/self.size,abs(yy-y)/self.size
        i +=1
        if xx <0 or yy <0 or xx > self.width - self.size or yy > self.width - self.size:
            return 1/ hypot(dis[0],dis[1])
        
def get_wall_dis(self,s_list): # Wall distance at 8 direction
    j = [[-1,0],[-1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[-1,1]]
    s = []
    for i in j:
        s.append(self.near_wall(i, s_list.copy()))
    s = np.asarray(s)
    return s

def near_food(self,fx,fy,n,s_list):# Head looks at 8 direction for the food
    a,b = n
    x,y = s_list.pop()
    i =0
    while True:
        xx = x +(self.size * i * a)
        yy = y +(self.size * i * b)
        dis = abs(x-fx)/self.size,abs(fy-y)/self.size
        i +=1
        if xx <0 or yy <0 or xx > self.width - self.size or yy > self.width - self.size:
                return 0
        else:
            if xx == fx and yy == fy:
                if dis[0] ==0 and dis[1] ==0:
                    return 0
                return 1/hypot(dis[0],dis[1])
            
                
def get_state(self,fx,fy,s_list,w): # Array of size 16
    j = [[-1,0],[-1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[-1,1]]
    s = []
    for i in j:
        s.append(self.near_food(fx,fy,i, s_list.copy()))
    s = np.asarray(s)
    a = np.append(w,s)
    return a

def reset(self): # Initialising the value when a new game is started
    self.agent.load_model()
    self.game_over = False
    self.wall_touch = False
    self.dirc = 'r'
    self.snake_length = 1
    self.snake_list = []
    
def startgame(self,e):
    sx,sy = 0,0 # Starting position of snake
    
    self.snake_list.append([sx,sy])
    fx,fy = 200,200 # Initial position of food
    step = 0
    action = 0 
    score = 0
    change = None
    wall = self.get_wall_dis(self.snake_list.copy())
    state = self.get_state(fx, fy, self.snake_list.copy(), wall)
    reward = 0
    t = 0
    save = False
    j = 0
    while not self.game_over:
        j +=1
        if j >500: # If snake struck in continuous loop
            print('Ended')
            break
        action = 0
                    
        action = self.agent.get_action(state)            
        if action ==1:
            change = 'l'
            step = 1
        elif action ==2:
            change = 'r'
            step = 1
        else:
            action = 0
            change = None
        
        if step == 0:
            step = 1
        else:
            t +=1
            save = True
            self.get_direction(change)
            change = None
            self.move(self.dirc,self.snake_list.copy())
        
        wall = self.get_wall_dis(self.snake_list.copy())
        new_state = self.get_state(fx, fy, self.snake_list.copy(), wall)
        
        if self.wall_touch:
            reward = -200
            print('Walled')
            self.agent.remember(state, action, reward, new_state, True)
            break
        
        food_collect = self.check_food_collect(fx, fy, self.snake_list.copy())
        if food_collect:
            reward += 50
            self.agent.remember(state, action, reward, new_state, False)
            save = False
            score +=1
            step = 0
            t = 0
            reward = 0
            fx,fy = self.food.food_pos(self.snake_list.copy())
            if fx == 0.1 and fy ==0.1:
                print('COMPLETED')
                pygame.quit()
                
        if save:
            save = False
            self.agent.remember(state, action, reward, new_state, False)

        self.display.fill((0,0,0))
        self.display_msg('Score :'+str(score))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display,(0,255,0),(fx,fy,self.size-1,self.size-1))
        self.display_player(self.display, self.snake_list,self.dirc)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        #time.sleep(1)
        state = new_state
        if e > 2500:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    print('E : {} , Epsilon :{:.2} , Score : {}'.format(e,np.float32(self.agent.epsilon),score))
    if e%10 ==0:
        self.agent.save_model()
    if len(self.agent.memory) > batch:
        self.agent.replay()

game = Game()
for e in range(10000):
    game.startgame(e)
    game.reset()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could try:

1. The way you have defined your state looks a little complicated. Won't top and bottom give the same information, one being negative of the other? Also if your snake head is at (1,1) and your fruit at (3,4), well then the fruit won't show up in the state at all. There will be very limited times when the snake agent can actually see the fruit. Maybe you can try defining the state another way?
2. In RL, things go south very frequently so it often makes sense to start with basic agents and basic games and move up the ladder. Try using the same agent for a simple openai gym environment like mountaincar, to check if the agent class works as intended.

Comment: You are right if the head is at (1,1) it dosen't detect the food if it is at (3,4). I tried with head looking at 16 directions. But it didn't work.